# IE8, Math.round() failure?

Tags: javascript, variables, internet-explorer-8, declaration

I did find this question: [Is Math.ceil() & Math.round() supported on IE8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409872/is-math-ceil-math-round-supported-on-ie8)

So I'm not sure what my problem is...

**Console Error**

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
>   functions.js, line 103 character 13

**functions.js, line 103**

```
percentLoaded = Math.round((appNumber / totalApps) * 100); //calculte loaded percent
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring the variable fixed the issue.

```
var percentLoaded;
```

Apparently IE9, IE10, Chrome and Firefox don't care, bt IE7 & IE8 required me to add the declaration a couple lines up.

Comment: You should *always* explicitly declare variables anyway.

Comment: Yeah, just overlooked it :)